# List to string conversion inside the Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, string, list, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe which was created using json data acquired from a web api.
Some of the objects are lists as per example output below. What is the best way to covert those lists into strings? The objective is to be able to remove [ ] and ' ' from each item, so, they dont show up as lists after dataframe's conversion to excel.

Example from Spyder console:
In [1248]: temp_work_df['domains']
Out[1248]:

```
0           [amazonaws.com]
1                        []
2                 [cox.net]
3                        []
4      [ctbctelecom.com.br]
         
93            [bigleaf.net]
94                       []
95                       []
96    [comcastbusiness.net, comcast.net]
97                       []
Name: domains, Length: 506, dtype: object
```

Example from xlsx after pd.excel (dont want to see closing/opening brackets or quotes in excel fields):

```
hostnames                                       domains
['ec2-35-174-167-57.compute-1.amazonaws.com']   ['amazonaws.com']
[]                                              []
['wsip-72-910-19-176.pn.at.cox.net']            ['cox.net']
[]                                              []
['189-132-203-031.static.ctbctelecom.com.br']   ['ctbctelecom.com.br']
['static-adsl190-7-152-179.etz.net.co']         ['etb.net.co']
['223.226.82.37.bc.googleusercontent.com']      ['googleusercontent.com']
['mxxxx.cbm.ncsu.edu']                          ['ndfu.edu']
```

Thanks,
GJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've shown, `temp_work_df['domains']` is a Series of lists, where each list contains one string or is empty.

Counter-intuitively, the way to access an element of all lists in a Series is using the `str` accessor, just like you would use to access a character in all strings in a Series.  So this will give you the first element of every list:

```
temp_work_df['domains'].str[0]
```

The result will be NaN for empty lists.  You can then replace it:

```
temp_work_df['domains'].str[0].fillna('')
```

Comment: Thanks! That's brilliant! Just tried it and it worked! Now I just need to figure out how to apply the same method for all other columns in the dataframe that have the same issue.  Thanks again!